# Add ±SE label with Mean labels on top of bar plots?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I am trying to add the mean ± standard error value **in text** on top of my bars, in my bar-chart. Like Excel does, sorta...
I have the mean, but I can't manage to find a way to add the standard error value as well (and even less a "±" symbol).

Is there a way to do so?

Here's my data (nh1), the code, and the graph I have for now.

```
dput(nh1)
traitement  N nombre_moules         sd         se         ci
1           canard 12    33.7500000 53.0696369 15.3198846 33.7188386
2       canard_lam  9    37.2222222 48.8102904 16.2700968 37.5189105
3              lam  9     0.4444444  0.5270463  0.1756821  0.4051236
4            nouee 12     0.8333333  1.4034589  0.4051437  0.8917153
5     nouee_canard  9   119.2222222 37.1274083 12.3758028 28.5386523
6 nouee_canard_lam 12    83.3333333 58.3225098 16.8362584 37.0563548
7        nouee_lam  9     4.3333333  4.3011626  1.4337209  3.3061663
8           temoin 12     0.5833333  1.2401124  0.3579896  0.7879298
```

Thank you for your help!

```
    nh1 <- summarySE(data = my_data_nombremoules, measurevar="nombre_moules", groupvars="traitement")
nh1

nh1$traitement <- factor(nh1$traitemeent)

ggplot(nh1, aes(x = traitement, y=nombre_moules
                                , fill=factor(traitement))) + 
  geom_bar(position=position_dodge(), stat="identity") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=nombre_moules-se, ymax=nombre_moules+se),
                width=.2,                    
                position=position_dodge(.9))

nh2 <- ggplot(nh1, aes(x = traitement, y=nombre_moules,
                        fill=factor(traitement))) + 
  geom_bar(position=position_dodge(), stat="identity") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=nombre_moules-se, ymax=nombre_moules+se),
                width=.2, position=position_dodge(.9)) + 
  stat_summary(fun=mean, colour="black", geom="point", size=2,show.legend = FALSE) +
  stat_summary(fun=mean, colour="black", geom="text",size=4, show.legend = FALSE, 
               vjust=-0.7, aes( label=round(nombre_moules, digits=1)))
```

[image: Graph I have for now]

(On a side note, I tried using geom_text instead of stat_summary for my mean labels, but I couldn't reduce the number of digits with digits=1, it gave me the "aesthetic unknown" error...)

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Could you provide a sample of your data? It will increase your chances of getting help. you can achieve this by using `dput(nh1)`. From my point of view I think that adding the SE labels are unnecessary as the graph is clear enough. You could increase the precision of the y-axis scale if you want to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear why you're using `stat_summary` here, since your data are already summarised. You can use `geom_point` and `geom_text` directly.

I have had to try to reclaim your data from your plot since you did not provide raw data in your question (see data used at the end of this answer)

I have to agree with DJJ in the comments: this looks messier with the SE labels attached. I have chosen `geom_label` here instead of `geom_text` to stop the numbers being obscured by the error bars.

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(nh1, aes(x = traitement, y=nombre_moules, fill = factor(traitement))) + 
  geom_col() +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = nombre_moules - se, ymax = nombre_moules + se), width =.2) + 
  geom_label(aes(label = paste(nombre_moules, "\ub1", se)), nudge_y = 5, size = 4,
             label.size = 0, label.r = unit(0, "pt"), fill = "#ebebeb") +
  geom_point(size = 3) +
  theme(legend.position = "none", axis.text.x = element_blank()) +
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL)
```

[image]

---

**Data used**

```
nh1 <- structure(list(traitement = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"), 
                      nombre_moules = c(33.8, 37.2, 0.4, 0.8, 119.2, 83.3, 4.3, 0.6), 
                      se = c(16, 16, 0.05, 0.05, 13, 17, 1, 0.1)), 
                 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you @Allan
I added my data summary to my original post (thank you DJJ for the tip). 

The code works, I now have the mean+SE! However, I couldn't manage to reduce the number of digits (for both the mean and the SE) like I could with the "summary" function. Is there a way to do so? It was originally what brought me to use stat.summary, because somehow I didn't manage to control that with geom_label or geom_text.

(If it's too off of the original question I can create a new topic-) 

Thanks a lot for your help, again.

Comment: @meclark you should just be able to do `paste(round(nombre_moules, 1), "\ub1", round(se, 1)))` instead of `paste(nombre_moules, "\ub1", se))` in my code.